# Check if a file extension is valid

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, validation, file-extension

I'm trying to get the file extension using `[string pathExtension]` but this does not always return the file extension per se. Eg: I have a file named 'Example.png', when I use this method I get 'png' which is correct. Now let's say I have a file with no extension, like 'Example', I get `nil` which is still correct. What happens when I have a file like 'Example.109'? I get '109' as the extension which is incorrect. It so happens that '.109' is part of the filename itself. Is there a way to validate this?

Comment: well it depends on what do you mean by valid ? a filename format isn't decided by the extension, but by the format of the file itself, if you tell more info about what files they are, we can help you know how to validate a file

Comment: In my case, the contents of the file don't matter at all. I am just concerned with getting the proper extension. So a valid extension would be something that is not incorrectly derived as in the case in question.

Comment: 109 is a valid extension, but it's only not valid for you. You need to validate it manually.

Comment: if a filename has 109 as an extension then this is the extension, it's not invalid, if you don't care about the contents of the file why are you trying to validate it ?

Comment: Is there a list of file extensions you're ok with? You could be comparing to that and if the result is not in there, you could reject the (make nil) the extension.

Comment: @irfan: The [iphone] tag is only appropriate for questions about the iPhone hardware, and periods are incorrect at the end of incomplete sentences like the title here. (You've also misspelled "grammar" in your edit description.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take your meaning of valid filename extension to be a filename extension for which there is an application present on the system that claims/declares that extension.

You can easily determine that by using the following code:

```
NSString *pathExtension = [@"Example.109" pathExtension];

NSLog(@"pathExtension == %@", pathExtension);

CFStringRef utiType = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(
       kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)pathExtension, NULL);

NSLog(@"utiType == %@", utiType);

CFDictionaryRef declaration = UTTypeCopyDeclaration(utiType);

NSLog(@"declaration == %@", declaration); // will likely print (null)


CFStringRef jpgUTIType = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(
         kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, CFSTR("jpg"), NULL);

NSLog(@"jpg's UTI Type == %@", jpgUTIType);

CFDictionaryRef knownDeclaration = UTTypeCopyDeclaration(jpgUTIType);

NSLog(@"knownDeclaration == %@", knownDeclaration);

if (utiType) CFRelease(utiType);
if (knownFilenameExtensionsUTIType) CFRelease(knownFilenameExtensionsUTIType);
if (declaration) CFRelease(declaration);
if (knownDeclaration) CFRelease(knownDeclaration);
```

That will likely print the following to console:

```
pathExtension == 109
utiType == dyn.age8xcqb3
declaration == (null)

jpg's UTI Type == public.jpeg
knownDeclaration == {
    UTTypeConformsTo = "public.image";
    UTTypeDescription = "JPEG image";
    UTTypeIdentifier = "public.jpeg";
    UTTypeTagSpecification =     {
        "com.apple.ostype" = JPEG;
        "public.filename-extension" =         (
            jpeg,
            jpg,
            jpe
        );
        "public.mime-type" =         (
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/jpg"
        );
    };
}
```

As you can see from the printed results, the call to `UTTypeCopyDeclaration()` for the UTI type associated with the `.109` filename extension returned `NULL`, which means there is no application that declares that filename extension. Compare that to the results returned for the `UTTypeCopyDeclaration()` call with the UTI type associated with the `.jpg` filename extension. There, the call returns a valid dictionary that contains the information, since there is an application (or the system itself) declares that filename extension.